# How to create gallery of inline elements with Fancybox 3?

Tags: php, html, fancybox, fancybox-3

I'm trying to create a gallery of inline elements with Fancybox 3. I've got the individual popups working, now I'm trying to figure out how to utilize Fancybox default navigation behavior for the user to be able to cycle through the popup elements.

Here is my code:

```
<ul id="testiFeed" class="list-unstyled">
                            <?php 
                                $args = array( 'post_type' => 'testimonial', 'posts_per_page' => 9 );
                                $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
                                $i = 1;
                                while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

                                  <li>
                                    <div class="testiPadding">
                                        <a data-fancybox data-src="#hidden-content-<?php echo $i ?>" href="javascript:;">
                                            <div class="testiBox" style="background-image: url(<?php the_post_thumbnail_url('medium_large'); ?>);">
                                                <p class="testiUser">@<?php the_field('instagram_username'); ?></p>
                                                <div class="testiCover"></div>
                                            </div>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                  </li>

                                  <div class="testiPopup" style="display: none;" id="hidden-content-<?php echo $i ?>">
                                    <div class="testiRow">
                                        <div class="testiHalf testiFeature" style="background-image: url(<?php the_post_thumbnail_url('large'); ?>);">

                                        </div>
                                        <div class="testiHalf testiRight">
                                            <div class="testiAuthor">
                                                <div class="testiProfile" style="background-image: url(<?php the_field('user_photo'); ?>);"></div>
                                                <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                                                <p><em><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i> @<?php the_field('instagram_username'); ?></em></p>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="testiContent">
                                                <?php the_content(); ?>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="testiShare">
                                                <p>Share <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a> <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a> <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-pinterest"></i></a></p>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                  </div>

                                <?php $i++; endwhile;
                            ?>
                        </ul>
```

I've tried adding rel="group1" and data-fancybox="group" to the anchor element that triggers the popup but no luck.

I've found other similar solutions but only for older versions of Fancybox which do not work with Fancybox 3.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Adding same value for `data-fancybox` should work fine - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mwaBZQ

Comment: Great, the keyboard navigation now works but there are still no arrows. The docs at http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/docs/ show default behavior to 'true' but I don't see the arrows and there are no errors in my console.

Thoughts?

Comment: Are you using fancyBox v3.1?